# updating data in a table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
`cart_item`

```
id, session_id, product_id, quantity
1   1           2           5
2   1           3           5
```

`product`

```
id, quantity
2   50
3   75
```

How to correctly update the data in the `product` table based on the data in the `cart_item` table? I want to update the quantity of products in the table `product`.
By updating the data in `product` I will delete all products in the table `cart_item`.
Here is what I would like to get when updating the data:
`product`

```
id, quantity
2   45
3   70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UPDATE ... JOIN` to calculate the value.

```
UPDATE product p 
JOIN cart_item ci ON ci.product_id = p.id
SET p.quantity = p.quantity - ci.quantity
```

[sqfliddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=910001bfbedd865d6621e4ed519fead0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a query like below

```
update p
set p.quantity = p.quantity - sum(ci.quantity)
from product p
join cart_item ci
on ci.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
```